# restarting console program with 1 key or exiting with all others

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic and want to restart a console program if the user inputs "1" and exit if they press any other key

I have used "Console.ReadLine" in conjunction with an If statement, but the trouble is I don't want them to have to press enter after their input.

Any help would be much appreciated and sorry if this is a basic question (no pun intended)

Comment: Please show the code you've already tried.

Comment: silly question but I do I break to new line? when I press enter it posts comment :(

Comment: @ronlaboa you can't use line breaks in comments ..

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ you can, just hit Shift+Enter

Comment: @JasonD you
mean
like
this? doesn't really work does it? it all displays as a single line..

Comment: Interesting, looks like it doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ReadLine, you can use ReadKey. This will not wait for the enter.

```
'Clear any keys from the input buffer
While Console.ReadKey(True)
End While

Dim MyKey = Console.ReadKey(True)
If MyKey.KeyChar = "1"c Then
  'We can act on the key since they pressed 1 (let the main application repeat)
Else
   'They pressed something else, we want to exit the application
End If
```

Comment: thank you so much, its the "MyKey.KeyChar I didn't know :D